# Composer psr-4 autoload

Tags: php, composer, autoload

Можно ли в автозагрузчике composer задать пути, если файлы имеют путь вида

app/modules/test/controllers
app/modules/test2/controllers
app/modules/test3/controllers

и т.д.

В старом проекте это выглядело примерно так

```
<?php 
 foreach($names as $name)
 {
   $namespaces[] = 'App/Modules/'.$name.'/Controllers';
 }
?>
```

и т.д.

Т.е. грубо говоря сделать в composer примерно так:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App/Modules/*/Controllers": "app/modules/*/controllers"
      }
}
```

Comment: Только прописать все папки вручную, либо привести `controllers` к `Controllers`.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо придется добавить файл автозагрузки отдельный, а хотел сделать красиво все :(

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте один файл (например autoload.php), который подключит все нужные классы и укажите его в конфиге composera

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
      "autoload.php"
    ]
}
```